# Программа не видит массив С

Tags: python, массивы

```
A=[]
A=[random.randint(1, 100)for x in range(10)]
print (*A)
for y in A:
    B=[y for y in A
           if y < 50]
    sum(B)
    b=sum(B)/len(B)
print ("Числа меншье 50: ", *B)
print ("Среднее арифметическое чисел меньше 50: ", b)
for n in A:
    С=[n for n in A
           if n >= 50]
    sum(C)
    c=sum(C)/len(C)
print(*C)
print(c)
```

не видит массив C не знаю что мне делать, пишет:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\python scripts\массив рандом числа и среднее арифмет.py", line 16, in 
>       sum(C)
>   NameError: name 'C' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно везде использовать латинскую букву C ;)

Кроме того, лишний мусор стоит выкинуть

```
import random
A=[]
A=[random.randint(1, 100)for x in range(10)]
print (*A)
B=[y for y in A if y < 50]
b=sum(B)/len(B)
print ("Числа меншье 50: ", *B)
print ("Среднее арифметическое чисел меньше 50: ", b)
C=[n for n in A if n >= 50]
c=sum(C)/len(C)
print(*C)
print(c)
```